# How to render list (slice) of string as list in yaml file by Helm Chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I have a list or (slice) of string data for example **[string1, string2, string3]**.
I want to render it in list fashion in yaml file as

```
- string1
- string2
- string3
```

How can I do that?

I have tried

```
{{- range $val := $list }}
  - {{ $val }}
{{- end }}
```

but it renders following as multiple line of strings

```
- |-
   - string1
   - string2
   - string2
```

any idea? thank you in advance

Comment: Helm's template rendering doesn't actually have a lot of YAML-specific knowledge; it just writes out what you give it as text and then tries to re-parse it as YAML.  Is there a line above this, or in a containing template, that contains the `- |-` block-string marker?

Comment: this happens in middle of the list, I guess because its happening in middle of the list it tries to render list of string as element in a list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use formatted string output to solve the problem.

eg.

values.yaml

```yaml
arr:
  - string1
  - string2
  - string3
```

_helpers.tpl

```yaml
{{/*
Print string from list split by ,
*/}}
{{- define "print.list" -}}
{{- range $idx, $val := $.Values.arr -}}
{{- if $idx }}
{{- print ", "  -}} 
{{- end -}}
{{- $val -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

The template you want to render, for example `comfigmap.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ include "test.fullname" . }}
data:
  test: [{{- include "print.list" .}}]
```

output

```yaml
piVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data:
  test: [string1, string2, string3]
```

---

---↓ 2022-01-05 update ↓---

values.yaml

```yaml
arr:
  - string1
  - string2
  - string3
```

The template you want to render, for example `comfigmap.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ include "test.fullname" . }}
data:
  test: |
    {{- toYaml $.Values.arr | nindent 4 }}
```

output

```yaml
piVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data:
  test: |
    - string1
    - string2
    - string3
```

---

no pipe

`helm --dry-run --debug template test .`

The template you want to render, for example `comfigmap.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ include "test.fullname" . }}
data:
  test: 
    {{- toYaml $.Values.arr | nindent 4 }}
```

output

```yaml
piVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data:
  test: 
    - string1
    - string2
    - string3
```

---

`range`

```yaml
{{- range $i, $v := $.Values.arr }}
- {{ $v }}
{{- end }}
```

output

```yaml
- string1
- string2
- string3
```

Comment: Thing is I want the final output as a list
data:
  test:
    - string1
    - string2
    - string3

Comment: If you want such a rendering result, then the operation will be simpler, see the updated reply above

Comment: Thank you for the response. The ideal way is to not to have that pipe | after `test:` field. I think to make this happend we might need to use `range`  or `with`

Comment: No need for the pipe symbol |, you can remove it completely, it is not necessary.

Comment: ```range``` can also be implemented, of course, but it is more convenient to display with ```toYaml``` here.